# How to find the parent class of a particular object in Android C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm currently having an issue where views in a RecycleView are being disposed, despite the Dispose function of the RecyclerView not being called (checked by setting variable) nor it being recycled (also checked by setting a variable).

The main issue: MvxPropertyChangedListener not being cleared. The listener then tries to perform an operation on the disposed view, causing an issue. No matter where I call listener.Clear() (from onViewRecycled in the RecycleView.Adapter, from Dispose, before we initially bind the ViewModel), I still  get 'object is disposed' exception.

A try-catch around the view in question 'fixes' the issue, but doesn't solve the root problem.

Question:
    In Xamarin, how do I track these RecycleViews? Through my try-catch, I can see which ones have the issue (which is why I can track whether it's disposed, recycled etc.) and the associated ViewModel, but do not then know how to track why and where these inner view objects are disposed?

Note: I have more experience with iOS dev. My Android understanding is fair but lacking atm.

Edit: Code provided.

```
public class CarouselViewHolder : BaseCarouselViewHolder
{

private SimpleProgressBar _progressBar;
// tile listener
private MvxPropertyChangedListener _tileListener;

private CarouselTileViewModel Tile => (Item as CarouselTileViewModel);

public SingleCarouselItemViewHolder(View v) : base(v)
{
    _progressBar = v.FindViewById<BasicProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);
}

public override void PrepareForReuse()
{
    ClearTileListener();
    base.PrepareForReuse();
}

public void SetTile(CarouselTileViewModel tile)
{
    // keep the item
    Item = tile;

    // progress bar
    RefreshProgressBar ();

    // listeners
    SetupTileListener();
}

private void SetupTileListener()
{
    ClearTileListener();

    // setup the listener for the item
    if(Item != null && Item is CarouselTileViewModel)
    {
        _tileListener = new MvxPropertyChangedListener(Item as CarouselTileViewModel);

        _tileListener.Listen (() => (Item as CarouselTileViewModel).Progress, RefreshProgressBar);
    }
}

private void RefreshProgressBar ()
{
    try
    {
        if (_progressBar != null)
        {
            _progressBar.Visibility = Tile.Progress > 0 ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
            _progressBar.SetProgress(Tile.Progress);
        }
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
    {
        Phx.TaggedError ("BasicProgressBar already disposed", "Exception {0}", e);
    }
}

private void ClearTileListener()
{
    // kill any old listeners
    if(_tileListener != null)
    {
        _tileListener.Clear();
        _tileListener.Dispose();
        _tileListener = null;
    }
}

public override void OnAttachedToWindow()
{
}

public override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
{
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    ClearTileListener();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
}

public class CarouselItemAdapter : BaseCarouselAdapter<CarouselViewModel>
{

    .
    .
    .

public override void OnViewAttachedToWindow(Java.Lang.Object holder)
{
    base.OnViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    if(holder is CarouselViewHolder)
    {
        (holder as CarouselViewHolder).OnAttachedToWindow();
    }
}

public override void OnViewDetachedFromWindow(Java.Lang.Object holder)
{
    base.OnViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    if (holder is CarouselViewHolder)
    {
        (holder as CarouselViewHolder).PrepareForReuse();
        (holder as CarouselViewHolder).OnDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}

public override void OnViewRecycled(Java.Lang.Object holder)
{
    base.OnViewRecycled(holder);
    if (holder is CarouselViewHolder)
    {
        (holder as CarouselViewHolder).PrepareForReuse();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: some code should be welcome!

Comment: @hugorgor: I provided code, but my question was of the general 'How do I do this?' type. Doesn't really pertain to the code, but if you have any suggestions I'm all ears.

Note. The dots refer to irrelevant portions of the code.

Answer (score 1):

With MvvmCross you shouldn't have to worry about writing your own ViewHolder or Adapter classes. The MvxRecyclerView takes care of implementing these classes and binds all of the ViewModels.

Define an MvxRecyclerView in your parent view:

```
<MvxRecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    local:MvxBind="ItemClick TileClickedCommand; ItemsSource Tiles;"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/tileitemview" />
```

Note the MvxItemTemplate, this is where you specify a secondary view to use for each of your TileViewModels.

Your child view can look as simple as something like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Format('{0:f}', Progress)" />
```

Note: I used a TextView to only represent how a child view will bind to a child ViewModel. The child view can contain any number of controls as you want.